# How to break up an HTML List using CSS Only

Tags: css, html-lists

I would like to create a list that adds columns as necessary depending on how many list elements are present. Currently I only know how to do this using a table, which I would like to avoid. Is there a way to do this using CSS only?

I have created an example of how I currently do it with tables on JSFiddle.net ...

http://jsfiddle.net/9W33K/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty thorough (albeit a bit older) guide I've looked at before here: [CSS Swag: Multi-Column Lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/)

Comment: Nice guide. Very thorough. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways I can think of that you can go about it.

1. Use Floats
2. Use CSS3 Columns

With floats you will get a pattern like this:

```
Item 1 Item 2
Item 3 Item 4
```

With CSS3, you don't get very much [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) (no IE support until IE10).

Fiddle with both examples: http://jsfiddle.net/DThhT/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic a HTML table using css `display:table` property. You'll be able to replace those `<tr>` and `<td>` with `<div>`.

More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display